# Retrieve Images from different folders

Tags: python-3.x, image, dimensions

I have a big folder and inside it has sub folders and i want to retrieve images from all those folders. How do i do it?
Second if i want to get dimensions of all those images how would i do that?

I have tried it with one folder and it is working fine. But i want to do it for multiple folders. I reading image dimensions of one folder from this code.

```
folder_images = "D:/DeepFashion/Category and Attribute Prediction/img/img"
size_images = dict()

for dirpath, _, filenames in os.walk(folder_images):
    for path_image in filenames:
        image = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dirpath, path_image))
        with Image.open(image) as img:
            width, heigth = img.size
            size_images[path_image] = {'width': width, 'heigth': heigth}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code seems to be fine - the only problem with it being that if *any* of the files in the folder structure is not a proper image file, you will get an unhandled exception and the script will stop.

Since you are not reading the images in a lazy way, the is no reason to use the `with` command to get to the images - just change your code to:

```py
folder_images = "D:/DeepFashion/Category and Attribute Prediction/img/img"
size_images = dict()

for dirpath, _, filenames in os.walk(folder_images):
    for path_image in filenames:
        image = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dirpath, path_image))
        try:
           img = Image.open(image)
        except OSError:
           print("Not an image file: ", image)

        width, heigth = img.size
        size_images[path_image] = {'width': width, 'heigth': heigth}
```

Comment: Thankyou for feed back but 'img' directory contains like 5000 sub folder and i have to loop through it to get images. all the file in sub directories are images.

Comment: so, what is _not_ working there? it should just work as is, with `os.walk`.